# Django 1.7 loads extraneous models when running tests

Tags: python, django

I have a Django project that worked well with Django 1.6, but is giving me a lot of trouble as I try to upgrade to Django 1.7.

In this project is an app, `my_app` which does not contain any models of its own, but contains a file `other_models.py`, [generated to interact with a legacy database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/legacy-databases/#auto-generate-the-models) using `python manage.py inspectdb`. I want to use these models only in specific code paths, when I'm connected to a this secondary database. Again, this worked fine with Django 1.6.

Having upgraded to Django 1.7, I am no longer able to run my test suite using `python manage.py test`. When I do this, I get a huge number of errors that look like the following:

```
CommandError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
my_app.AccountAccount.created_by_type: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'AccountAccount.created_by_type' clashes with reverse accessor for 'AccountAccount.deactivated_by_type'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'AccountAccount.created_by_type' or 'AccountAccount.deactivated_by_type'.
...
# Tons more of these
```

These errors are all complaining about models defined in `other_models.py`. It appears to me that the [changes in app-loading process](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/releases/1.7/#app-loading-refactor) are causing my problems, but I'm not entirely sure.

I have tried setting up an `apps.py` in this app with the following code:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'my_app'
    models_module = None
```

and added `default_app_config = 'my_app.apps.MyAppConfig'` to my `my_app.__init__.py`, as per the [documentation on configuring applications](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/applications/#configuring-applications), but to no avail.

I'm at a total loss for what to do next, and would appreciate any information regarding how to control when and how Django attempts to load models, especially when running `python manage.py test`.